# Where does Kivy store all the instances of the classes from __main__?

Tags: python, kivy

So I'm wondering, where does Kivy (or Python, for that matter) hold all these instances of the class? And how do I reference 'homebase' from a class?

For example, `self` from within a method calls directly to the instance of the class. This is really helpful, because I can directly modify the object itself.

But if I'm creating a method from a different class, I don't know how to find that list/dict that contains all the other instances from the .kv code because I didn't write the code.

Another way to put it: If the code were like a filing cabinet, I'm wondering in what folder might I be able to pull out each individual instance that's been instantiated from my code?

Especially given Kivy's proclivity to instantiate on my behalf from the .kv file. I wonder where it puts all those objects instantiated from the class.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a little? It's hard to understand what exactly do you want to know

Comment: (Edited) For example, 'self' from within a method calls directly to the instance of the class. If the code were like a filing cabinet, I'm wondering in what folder might I be able to pull out each individual instance that's been instantiated from my code? 

Especially given Kivy's proclivity to instantiate on my behalf from the .kv file. I wonder where it puts all those objects instantiated from the class.

Comment: No help? :(    Hmmm.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#locals) and [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#globals) to access all accessible instances, however it's kind of tricky because it returns even strings, ints, etc. What you can do is probe the dictionary recursively and before each new recursive call do this:

```
if not isinstance(key, (int, str, ...)):
    dig_deeper()
```

which should provide you a way to dig through all instances and basically find them. However, if there was something like:

```
FloatLayout()
```

or

```
Color()
```

or anything not stored elsewhere as a variable, you might not be able to access it. `Color()`, however will be stored somewhere in the `canvas`, so that should be easy if you know where to look.